# Convert date with month/day/year/time/ am or pm to date format in pipe using lubridate in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I would like to convert the following date to an R date format:

```
"12/5/2018 11:49:29 PM"
```

I can accomplish this with base R:

```
as.POSIXlt("12/5/2018 11:49:29 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2018-12-05 23:49:29 PST"
```

I'm wondering what the lubridate equivalent is. I checked the CRAN documentation and other stackof questions but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just use `mdy_hms("12/5/2018 11:49:29 PM")` it should pick up.  Also check with `pm(`

Comment: `parse_date_time("12/5/2018 11:49:29 PM", 'dmY IMS p')` works also